# Magento 1.9 - Upload multiple files from product view page front end

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file-upload, varien-file-uploader

I am using product custom option "input type file" to upload multiple files from front end (for customer) but can't upload multiple files.

I need help to uploads multiple files from front end using single input(File).
After uploads, files name should be shown on cart page and in order detail.

[image]

Thanks